# Dual Boot Parition Amount Reduction

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage, disk-management

I have a 111GB unallocated partition from setup of a win10/Ubuntu dual boot. How do I reallocate that unused 111gb back to the C drive? I tried using the Windows Disk Format thing to no avail.

Comment: Fixed it. Disregard please.

Answer (score 0):

Boot up with a liveUSB (try Ubuntu without installing) and launch `gparted`

Use it to extend the previous partition and thus reclaim those 111GB